# ItextPDF dependency not found by Maven

Tags: java, maven, itext

I have the following dependency declared in my `pom.xml` file

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>itext7-core</artifactId>
    <version>7.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I'm working in Intellij and it says it's not found.  It also won't let me import anything from the `com.itextpdf` packages.

I've tried a couple clean builds and restarts with no change. I also tried adding the itextpdf repository to the POM file with no change.

Comment: this dependency is a pom, so try `<type>pom</type>` !(?)

Answer (score 0):

it is

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itext7-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>itext7-core</artifactId>
    <version>7.2.0</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```